# Reduction from second oder to first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I wanted to ask how you can reduce an equation of the form  **y'' + my + y^n=0** to first order. Any resources to figure this out or direction could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$ y'' + my + y^n=0 $$
Multiply by $y'$:
$$ y'y'' + myy' + y'y^n=0 $$
$$ \dfrac 12 (y'^2)' + \dfrac m2(y^2)' + \dfrac 1 {n+1}(y^{n+1})'=0 $$
Integrate to reduce the order:

$$  y'^2 + my^2 + \dfrac 2 {n+1}y^{n+1}=C $$

Comment: Thank you, what is the method called so that I can read on it, I feel stuck at the moment and anything I can better read to improve my understanding would be welcome

Comment: @Craques you're welcomed.  I don't know if this method has a specific name. If it does I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to define a new variable and make it a system of two equations, so  $$y'=z\\z'=-my-y^n$$

Comment: Thank you, what is the method called so that I can read on it, I feel stuck at the moment and anything I can better read to improve my understanding would be welcome

Comment: I have seen it usually discussed in numerical analysis texts.  The methods there are usually designed for first order equations, so this is what you do for second (or higher) order ones.  You now have a vector valued first order equation, so you have to vectorize the method, but that is standard.  I haven't seen much discussion.